# How to insert a new line after a text in javascript

Tags: javascript

i m appending text values in a string and on each iteration i want to move to a new line. my code is :

```
$lblEmployee.html($lblEmployee.html()+"  "+ dataEmployees[i]["FirstName"] +" " + criteriaTestedEmployees[i]["LastName"]);
```

I tried putting `\n` at the end like :

```
$lblEmployee.html($lblEmployee.html()+"  "+ dataEmployees[i]["FirstName"] +" " + criteriaTestedEmployees[i]["LastName"] + "\n");
```

But it doesn't work.

May someone pls suggest a way..Thanks in advance..

Comment: In HTML, you should use the `<br />` tag to append a newline.

Comment: @PremanshuMishra well then you should select an answer from one of the three that were given... Usually the one who answered first.

Comment: @PremanshuMishra you should click the checkmark next to an answer in order to give credit to the person who gave you the answer.. and also since all of the answers are about the same it would be proper to give upvotes to them also.

Comment: @Laurence I m new to Stack Overflow. Will maintain the standards for sure..This time i acknowledged all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `<br>` instead of the \n since that is correct HTML syntax for a new line

Answer (score 0):

Use `<br/>` instead of `\n` because it's html rather than plain text.

If you look in the source code, you are actually creating a new line with `\n` but only in the source code. Whitespace like `\n` is ignored when creating the DOM tree.